# How to change the color values of the operating system

Tags: colors, operating-system, image-manipulation, gpu

I'm doing research about a schoolproject. The project is to develop a program that can change the colors of the screen (of the OS aswell of all programs that run on it). The endproduct is supposed to be a single program that is able to change the colors by input (i.e. increasing the presentness of a primary color, for instance add 10% RED), and is an experimental approach to manipulating color blindness. I've already done the theoretical biological research, now I'm looking into the practical deployment of such an application.

I have not set on a single programming language, as I do not know which ones would be the best for, let's say, the windows 7 environment. (which language features the easiest/fastest function calls, for example)

Some examples of function calls I intend to program:

- GetColorValues (return data about the current colors the pixels of the screen are displaying)
- ProcessColorValues (A simple modification of all respective colors returned by the function above)
- SetColorValues (Return the modified colors back to their respective places on the screen)

I would prefer being able to intercept the data whilst it is being pipelined to the screen, in order to keep the processing smooth.

Technically now, I don't really know where to start. I don't even know if I'm supposed to look into the OS, or the drivers of the graphics card.

I was hoping someone could guide me and tell me what I should look for, or where I could find these.

Thanks for reading.

Arnaud

Answer (score 1):

The Windows [Monitor Configuration Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775232.aspx) could be a starting point - for example the [SetMonitorRedGreenOrBlueGain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775246.aspx) function to boost specific colors. You should be able to call these functions from C# or VB.Net using [PInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)